# php - data entry and order issue

Tags: php

Im having a little trouble with a php script ive made.

you can see all the relevant info at http://click-media.co.uk/Client/Lisa/Admin/admin.php (password: "hey")

I basically need the classes to be ordered by day/time when a new class is created, either by changing the column names in the database to a timestamp or something or by making a new column to and ordering it by this.. then using the php to switch the order values when the admin clicks "moveup"/"move down" next to the row.

any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I didn't read your question, but your `delete.php` isn't checking for authentication or session before performing deletion. Anyone can do this `delete.php?ID=SOMETHING` and delete from your database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement this by doing the following:

- Add a column in the database and call it `class_order`
- Your SQL query should have `ORDER BY class_order`
- Moving up `UPDATE table set class_order = THE_ORDER_OF_THE_CLASS_ABOVE WHERE id = TARGET_CLASS` and `UPDATE table set class_order = TARGET_CLASS_ORDER WHERE id = THE_CLASS_ABOVE`
- Moving down is the opposite of moving up

Comment: @scriptmonkey, don't forget to check my comment on your question. Very important.